# How to get the table name from a field in a join query with MSSQL? (mysql_field_table equivalent)

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado, tablename

I'm doing a query manager in Delphi using `ADO`, I need to know all fields that will be returned by a query, does no matter how complex and how much joins they will have. I want to call a function, that return to me, all fields that will be returned in a specific query, and fields information, like table what is this field from.

In mysql with php, I have the command `mysql_field_table`, in this command I pass the result object and the field index and this command return the table name for me.

Well, that is my dream, get the table name from a field index in a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM TableOne Left Join Table2 ON Table2.MasterField = Table1.KeyField
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a `TADODataSet` to fetch the `Recordset`, iterate the `Fields` collection, and get the tables/fields names like this:

```
for I := 0 to ADODataSet1.Recordset.Fields.Count - 1 do
begin
  TableName := ADODataSet1.Recordset.Fields[i].Properties['BASETABLENAME'].Value;
  FieldName := ADODataSet1.Recordset.Fields[i].Properties['BASECOLUMNNAME'].Value;
end;
```

Comment: You dont know how much you help me. very very very thanks... im very gratefull... you are the best!!! sorry but I dont have reputation to vote, but feel your self voted!

Comment: +1 didn't know this was possible. Is this property generic for all database types?

Comment: @whosrdaddy, Iv'e used it with MSSQL, and MS-ACCESS. it is depended on the provider (among other things). Look at a related information: [When Table Name Is Available Using ADO, RDO, DAO](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/204848)