# How to get the table name from a column in a join query with SQL Server and FIREDAC?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, firedac, database-metadata

I looking for get metadata on a `TFDQuery` (FireDAC).

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Code = t2.code
```

I would like to know the column information (table name, the real column name in the table, ....)

I find this post : [How to get the table name from a field in a join query with MSSQL? (mysql_field_table equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431830/how-to-get-the-table-name-from-a-field-in-a-join-query-with-mssql-mysql-field) but I have not the same structure on FireDac.

Comment: I think you will need to fetch meta data as well. I can try to check this out later.

Comment: Take a look at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Extended_Metadata_(FireDAC) and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Working_with_Metadata_(FireDAC)

Comment: @RBA, yep, I meant these (they are called extended meta data, not just meta data) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As RBA already mentioned you have to enable *ExtendedMetaData* in the connection first. When done you can get the field column description via `query.GetFieldColumn(field)` and access the table and column name with its `ActualOriginTabName` and `ActualOriginColName` properties.

```
column := query.GetFieldColumn(field);
orgTableName := column.ActualOriginTabName;
orgColumnName := column.ActualOriginColName;
```